# React - persist state in local storage using react-numeric-input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I'm rendering this in a bootstrap table using `react-numeric-input` library:

```
          <td>
              <NumericInput
                value={
                  0
                }
                onChange={handleOnChange}
                step={0.01}
                mobile={false}
                size="14"
              />
            </td>
```

and these are the bits of code to handleOnChange:

```
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  const handleOnChange = event => {
    localStorage.setItem('myValueInLocalStorage', event.target.valueAsNumber);
    setValue(event.target.valueAsNumber);
  };
```

I get this error back:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueAsNumber' of undefined
```

I'm new to React and hooks so managing state is a bit problematic for me. All I want to do is change the input value and persist it in local storage so when browser is refreshed, it remembers the last value...

OK UPDATE

So I've made some progress, this bit of code actually avoids the error:

```
const handleOnChange = event => { const value = event; localStorage.setItem('myValueInLocalStorage', value); setValue(parseFloat(value)); };
```

The value then goes into local storage but the input box itself does not change in value... stumped...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const handleOnChange = event => {
  const value = parseInt(event.target.value);
  localStorage.setItem('myValueInLocalStorage', value);
  setValue(value);
};
```

Comment: any error? you received like above? you an also log console.log(value) to see the text of input

Comment: Yes it's the same error unfortunately: 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

When I console.log(value) it does not even show up in console...